# Sacar el min. y el max. de una variable con la siguiente código:

Tags: r, rstudio

Necesito sacar el min. y el max. de una variable con el siguiente código pero no soy capaz de hacerlo. Es de la variable population del marco de datos de gapminder en R studio. Alguien podría darme una pista?

Saludos!!

```
filter(___ == max (____))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(dslabs)
```

Puedes usar:

```
gapminder %>% filter(population == max(population,na.rm = T))
gapminder %>% filter(population == min(population,na.rm = T))
```

o bien:

```
min(gapminder$population,na.rm = T)
max(gapminder$population,na.rm = T)
```

Comment: mil gracias!!! Me funcionó!! :)